# ¿Por qué no me funciona el if que identifica una sección?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un ingreso de sección que tiene dos roles admin y usuario, la cosa es que cuando intento hacer la verificación del identificador de sección en una página no diferencia la sección o eso pienso yo porque por ejemplo: si me meto desde un usuario que no es administrador y copio la url de la página de admins y lo pego en el rol de usuario igual lo lleva a la página. Si alguno me explica les agradecería muchísimo que me explicaran por qué pasa eso, tal vez estoy fallando en la creación de identificador de sección o en la validación de sección, me inclino más por esta.

```js
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
  header("Location:../pagina-productos.php");
}
 ?>
```

```html
$sentencia = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email =?");
$sentencia->execute(array($user));
$result = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



if (is_array($result)==true) {
  if (password_verify($password, $result['password']) && $result['nivel']==1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario']="$user";
  header("Location:../pagina-productos.php");
  exit();


}else if (password_verify($password, $result['password']) && $result['nivel']==2) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['admin']="$user";
  header("Location:../levelup/products-ingrese.php");
  exit();


}else{
  echo'<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
      window.location.href="../index.php";
      </script>';
      exit();
}
}else {
  echo'<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
      window.location.href="../index.php";
      </script>';
      exit();
}
 ?>
```

```html
<?php
unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
unset($_SESSION['admin']);
session_destroy();

header("Location:../../index.php");

 ?>
```

Comment: Solo debes tener un `session_start()` y, de preferencia, al inicio del _script_. Luego, si el usuario no es administrador, solo usa `unset($_SESSION['admin']);`. Seguramente habías ingresado como administrador y olvidaste eliminar esa variable antes de ingresar con el otro usuario.

Comment: ¿Cuando tengo que eliminar la variable lo debo hacer en el mismo archivo en el que uso el session_destroy() ?, porque aún haciéndolo en ese archivo si ingreso una vez con el admin y copio el link y ingreso nuevamente como usuario y pego el link me deja ver la página

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código donde terminas la sesión.

Comment: Si no pones `session_start();` al inicio del script, no tienes acceso a las variables de sesión y, por tanto, los `unset()` y `session_destroy();` no tienen efecto.

Comment: Siempre que quieras tener acceso a variables de sesión debes usar `session_start();`